# Export to wavefront always gives white for ambient ka

Tags: export

I'm using 2.76b on ubuntu. When I export to a wave front object, it will always set the material's ambiance (ka) as white. I've changed the World ambient color to multiple different colors, and it always exports as white.

Steps I use:

1. Create new blender file w/ default cube
2. Click on World tab in properties.
3. Expand World subsection
4. Set Ambient to pink or something
5. File -> Export -> WaveFront

When I go to open up the .mtl file, it will still show as all 1's for the ka component for any material.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it appears that the export script just applies the ambient property in the shading sub section, which is a single value between 1 and zero that's just a multiplier for how much the global ambience the material receives.  It puts the single value as the component for each of the RGB values for ka upon export.

Comment: Nowadays it seems to use either all-white, or the value of the metallic property if that is set. As a workaround I am setting metallic to 0.001. See https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/bdb57541475f20ccc4f6e5f8fc075ac424becc19/source/blender/io/wavefront_obj/exporter/obj_export_mtl.cc#L275-L280